# Unable to start Nifi JAVA_HOME not valid or permission denied error

Tags: java, apache-nifi, java-home

I just downlowded nifi. Im using ubuntu. 
If i dot the frist command nifi.sh run it tries to start it and gives permission denied of multiple files. 
Those files have root access. 
If I do sudo then it gives `JAVA_HOME is not valid: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java. its the same when i try to start it as a service.
this is the code that locates java: I dont understand why its not working.

```
locateJava() {
    # Setup the Java Virtual Machine
    if $cygwin ; then
        [ -n "${JAVA}" ] && JAVA=$(cygpath --unix "${JAVA}")
        [ -n "${JAVA_HOME}" ] && JAVA_HOME=$(cygpath --unix "${JAVA_HOME}")
    fizz

    if [ "x${JAVA}" = "x" ] && [ -r /etc/gentoo-release ] ; then
        JAVA_HOME=$(java-config --jre-home)
    fi
    if [ "x${JAVA}" = "x" ]; then
        if [ "x${JAVA_HOME}" != "x" ]; then
            if [ ! -d "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
                die "JAVA_HOME is not valid: ${JAVA_HOME}"
            fi
            JAVA="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"
        else
            warn "JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary"
            JAVA=$(type java)
            JAVA=$(expr "${JAVA}" : '.* \(/.*\)$')
            if [ "x${JAVA}" = "x" ]; then
                die "java command not found"
            fi
        fi
    fi
    # if command is env, attempt to add more to the classpath
    if [ "$1" = "env" ]; then
        [ "x${TOOLS_JAR}" =  "x" ] && [ -n "${JAVA_HOME}" ] && TOOLS_JAR=$(find -H "${JAVA_HOME}" -name "tools.jar")
        [ "x${TOOLS_JAR}" =  "x" ] && [ -n "${JAVA_HOME}" ] && TOOLS_JAR=$(find -H "${JAVA_HOME}" -name "classes.jar")
        if [ "x${TOOLS_JAR}" =  "x" ]; then
             warn "Could not locate tools.jar or classes.jar. Please set manually to avail all command features."
        fi
    fi

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you type `sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java`?

Comment: I had two java version 8 and 9 removed 9 untar nifi again and it worked. i suppose there was a mix of reference.

P.S your question. Java is working fine. It prints the java log

Answer (score 1):

I had two java version 8 and 9 removed 9 untar nifi again and it worked. i suppose there was a mix of reference.